# CartoCSS: labels along inside of polygon boundary

Tags: openstreetmap, polygon, labeling, mapnik, cartocss

I'm using CartoCSS to render maps that include large polygons (like national parks). At higher zoom levels I want labels along the inside of the polygon boundaries, like in OpenStreetMap:

[image]

I reviewed the [openstreetmap-carto](https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto) stylesheets but could not find how this is done. Using `text-placement: line` just places text on the line (this is how streets are labelled). I need it **inside** the line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to add this

```
text-dy: -10;
```

you can look at file `admin.mss` in `openstreetmap-carto` project dir
and find code

```
#nature-reserve-text[zoom >= 13][way_pixels > 192000] {
  text-name: "[name]";
  text-face-name: @book-fonts;
  text-fill: green;
  text-halo-radius: 1.0;
  text-halo-fill: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  text-placement: line;
  text-dy: -10;
}
```

it will done what you want

and you can also add `text-spacing: 30;` option 
it will set the repeat words distance